# How to add Custom Fields to Order and Quote

Tags: magento

i am trying to create custom text field on checkout page as shipping method section by follow by given link ( 
http://tutorialsformagento.blogspot.in/2014/06/add-custom-fields-to-order-and-quote.html)

Step 1 is working fine and text fields are showing but i want to save it in order table if proceed to next step

Step 2 (Save the field in Quote and Order Tables) is confusing me in which folder and file i write **installer** code.

so please help me in which location i save installer code becoz i am new in magento.

Thanks